# on listview click mp3 is not playing

Tags: android, listview, android-mediaplayer, android-storage

I am working on mp3 Player to play mp3 files, in this way i am gettling all mp3 from specific folder but the problem is when i click the list view to play song its not playing it crash the app
Main Activity

```
 String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Music";
    Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
    File f = new File(path);
    File file[] = f.listFiles();
    Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ file.length);
    for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
    {
        //here populate your listview
        Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + file[i].getName());
        songlist.add(file[i].getPath());
        lv.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
    }

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("song", songlist.get(i));
                startActivity(intent);
```

Intent Activity to play song

```
 songitem =getIntent().getExtras().getInt("song");
   mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,songitem);
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried till now and explain more when you say `not getting proper answer`.

Comment: i dont know the method how to get mp3 file from internal storage

Comment: Question Edited please check  now